# Nested Inner Join With Outer Join in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, inner-join

I've reviewed some of the previous questions regarding this topic and can't seem to get an answer to my issue.

I have 3 tables (Lot, Menu, SKU).

I need all the ingredients in Menu and their associated Product names in SKU for a given SKU, even if there is no associated row in LOT

My current query:

```
    select m.IngrSKU, m.IngMeasurementID, s.productName, m.quantity as   mQuantity, l.quantity, l.lot 
    from (Menu m 
    inner join sku s on m.ingrsku = s.sku)
    left outer join lot l on m.ingrsku + '-070516j' = l.lot and l.destinationid = 2 
    where m.skutype = 4 and m.SKU = '1321'
```

I read that the outer join has to come after the inner, but I'm still getting the "Join Expression Not Supported" error.

Any ideas?

Update:  this query provides the desired resultset in SQL Server; just can't get it to run in Access

Comment: Left Outer Join in Access is Left Join

Comment: Maybe Access does have a weird limitation here: "OUTER JOINs can be nested inside INNER JOINs in a multi-table join, but INNER JOINs cannot be nested inside OUTER JOINs."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @random_answer_guy:  i tried with left join and got the same result.

Comment: @shawn00  i looked at other questions answered which suggested reversing the order or doing two left joins (which would not work in this instance).  wondering if anyone has a suggestion for this or a way to rewrite the query (sub query, perhaps?)

Comment: @Jeff0 Although Access had it's quirkiness there is no logical reason to write the joins in any particular order. Other platforms would have accepted your query either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try without the brackets?

```
select m.IngrSKU, m.IngMeasurementID, s.productName, m.quantity as , mQuantity, l.quantity, l.lot 
from Menu m 
join sku s on m.ingrsku = s.sku
left join lot l on m.ingrsku + '-070516j' = l.lot and l.destinationid = 2 
where m.skutype = 4 and m.SKU = '1321'
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was with the multiple conditions in the left join.

I added parens and it solved it.

```
    select m.IngrSKU, m.IngMeasurementID, s.productName, m.quantity as   mQuantity, l.quantity, l.lot 
    from (Menu m 
    inner join sku s on m.ingrsku = s.sku)
    left outer join lot l on (m.ingrsku + '-070516j' = l.lot and l.destinationid = 2) 
    where m.skutype = 4 and m.SKU = '1321'
```

Comment: Very odd. I don't do much Access but I don't recall ever seeing parens there.

Answer (score -1):

```
    select y.IngrSKU, y.IngMeasurementID, y.productName, 
y.quantity as   mQuantity, y.quantity, y.lot  
    from  ((select *
        from Menu m 
        inner join sku s on m.ingrsku = s.sku ) x
        left outer join lot l on x.ingrsku + '-070516j' = l.lot 

and l.destinationid = 2 ) y
        where y.skutype = 4 and y.SKU = '1321'
```